# Show that $\partial_i A_j - \partial_j A_i = \epsilon_{ijk}B_k$

Tags: homework-and-exercises, magnetic-fields, differentiation, vector-fields, mathematics

Let us start from $\textbf{B}=\nabla \times \textbf{A}$ and write its components $B_k=\epsilon_{ijk}\partial_i A_j$.

I want to show that $\partial_i A_j - \partial_j A_i = \epsilon_{ijk}B_k$. I can sense that it works, but I want to see it directly. How should I start?

Comment: Contract with $\epsilon_{ijk}$ and figure out what the contraction of two $\epsilon$-symbols is.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using [the identity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levi-Civita_symbol#Index_and_symbol_values) $\epsilon_{kij}\epsilon_{klm}=\delta_{il}\delta_{jm}-\delta_{im}\delta_{jl}$,$$\epsilon_{ijk}B_k=\epsilon_{ijk}\epsilon_{klm}\partial_lA_m=(\delta_{il}\delta_{jm}-\delta_{im}\delta_{jl})\partial_lA_m=\partial_iA_j-\partial_jA_i=F_{ij}.$$